# Sum monthly amount and output for last day of month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have table like [example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8GaQ.png)

here is summed amount by day. i need sum amount by month and join that value for last day of month, pls see image [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOIro.png)

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need it like that? The desired output looks a bit off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.amount, t.dt, CASE WHEN month_cnt = rn THEN s ELSE NULL END AS month_s FROM (
    select your_table.*, 
    sum(amount) over(partition by year(dt), month(dt) ) s,
    count(*) over(partition by year(dt), month(dt)) month_cnt,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by year(dt), month(dt)  order by dt) rn

    from your_table 
)t 
order by dt
```

Comment: You're welcome, if this is an answer on your question, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
create table #test
(
    amount int,
    trans date
)

insert into #test
SELECT
    30, '2017-02-15'
UNION
SELECT
    20, '2017-02-18'
UNION
SELECT
    25, '2017-02-25'
UNION
SELECT
    10, '2017-03-22'
UNION
SELECT
    80, '2017-03-23'
UNION
SELECT
    54, '2017-04-11'


SELECT
    DATEPART(month, trans) month, SUM(amount) Sum
FROM
    #test
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(month, trans)
```